# ON DUPLICATE KEY insert new row instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem.

This is the SQL code I get:

```
INSERT INTO matches (match_id, league_name, league_id, test_one) 
VALUES (866860, 'Portugal',1,'testing') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE league_name = 
  CASE match_id 
    WHEN 866860 
      THEN 'Portugal' END, 
league_id = 
  CASE match_id 
    WHEN 866860 
      THEN 1 END, 
test_one = 
  CASE match_id 
    WHEN 866860 
      THEN 'testing' END
```

The problem is, that it always insert a new row instead of updating the existing one.
Is it because I need to make the "match_id" as `AUTO_INCREMENT` or anything else (at the moment, my "id" field is `AUTO_INCREMENT`)

Comment: What is the table definition? It might be missing the appropriate index.

Comment: You can also use `REPLACE INTO`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Here is my structure for "match_id" which the call should check after (http://d.pr/i/XF6Q) - don't know if I'm missing something there

Comment: @SimonThomsen, that doesn't like a key. If you have no keys defined, there will never be a duplicate key.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Is Replace into a better solution that on duplicate key?

Comment: @SimonThomsen maybe not better, certainly more readable

Comment: Could you run `DESCRIBE matches` and post the result so we can see the complete table definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is irrelevant here. But [ON DUPLICATE **KEY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) requires a key. More specifically, a unique key, such as primary key or a unique index.

Given the column names, I suspect that `match_id` fails to be a primary key.

**Update:** You also write a complicate set of `CASE ... END` constructs. Have a look at the [VALUES()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling your database to update information "ON DUPLICATE KEY"; if none of the other fields are UNIQUE keys, the database will insert a new row.

You can either SELECT the `id` before this query (or making it a sub-query) or add another key to this table that will result in a unique value for each row.  I don't know about your schema, but you might be able to create a multi-part key which spans `match_id` and `league_id`.